# How to get the CPU load by core in percentage?

Tags: top

I want to know CPU load of each core in a percentage.
I execute `top` and then press `1`
Output is something like this:

```
%Cpu0  :  0.0 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

- What does each column mean?
- Where is the % column?
- Can I add it?

Comment: Hmmm.....have you taken a look at the man page?

Comment: @mdpc `top` manual page fails to explain what the `id` column means. Neither does it explains which columns to consider when computing CPU activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all columns but the `id` (idle), `wa` (io wait) and the `st` (stolen) ones to get the CPU load.

You'll find most columns meaning in the `top` manual page:

```
       us, user    : time running un-niced user processes
       sy, system  : time running kernel processes
       ni, nice    : time running niced user processes
       wa, IO-wait : time waiting for I/O completion
       hi : time spent servicing hardware interrupts
       si : time spent servicing software interrupts
       st : time stolen from this vm by the hypervisor
```

Comment: thanks! probably i can use another tool which can "add everything for me"?

Comment: Sure, I would use `awk` but many alternatives might do it too.